# How get attributes of field from IME (SoftKeyboard, InputMethodService)

Tags: java, android, ime

I create my own Input Methods (IME). How best way to get attributes of current field in current alient application?
I need get:

- consecutive number of current field in alient form;
- total number of fields in the form;
- field is the first in the form (can i navigate to backward);
- field is the last in the form (can i navigate to forward);
- edited or not edited field.

For example, I find another attributes, can get:

`getCurrentInputEditorInfo().packageName` - get current alient application name (for example, `"com.application.currentname`"`).

`getCurrentInputEditorInfo().inputType` - get current edited type of field ([inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html), for example, "33d"  TYPE_CLASS_TEXT & TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS).

What is best way get attributes of current field? Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'field'? Are you referring to the `EditText`?

Comment: Yes, in my code - EditText. In general case - any editable view.